# How to log TLS version in Azure

Tags: azure, tls1.2

I am trying to diagnose a possible TLS 1.2 vs 1.0 issue.  We have an Azure subscription with the following Network Security Group, Application Gateway, and Application Services.  We have white listed IPs in the NSG and require TLS 1.2 in the AG.  We have an issue from one partner that is hitting our API.  Transactions from one of their data centers work and transactions from another are not making it to the API.

We have white-listed both data centers.  We have enabled a Network Watcher in Azure with flow logging and can confirm that we are receiving the requests from both datacenters.  Logging shows all traffic is to port 443.  We suspect that one datacenter is using TLS 1.2 and the other is not.

Is there any way to log which version of TLS is used by a request?